# How to use DecimalFormat

Tags: java, decimal, decimalformat

So I was trying to get a approximate value of pi and I tried using DecimalFormat but it didn't work well

My code

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MonteCarlo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        double m = 0, rnumber, result;
        int count = 0, choosenOne;
        
        Random generator = new Random();
        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
        ArrayList<Integer> n = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        n.add(100);
        n.add(10000);
        n.add(1000000);
        n.add(100000000);
        n.add(1000000000);
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            choosenOne = n.get(i - 1);

            while (count <= choosenOne * 4)
            {
                rnumber = generator.nextDouble(4);
                
                if (rnumber <= Math.PI)
                    m++;

                count++;
            }
            
            result = m / choosenOne;
            
            System.out.println(choosenOne + ": " + fmt.format(result));
        }
    }
}
```

My Output:

100: 3.14

10000: 3.1379

1000000: 3.141689

100000000: 3.141726

1000000000: 0.314173

Comment: 1_000_000_000 is approximately 2^30, times 4 it overflows 32 int, 2^32. Hence the calculation goes ends in chaos (negative product likely), the while skipped, divided by 10 more. Result 0.314.

Comment: What can I do to fix that? I can't get any input with Long and if I add an if statement that multiplies the number with 10 if its below 1 for 5th one but it becomes same with 4th

Comment: first: please change your code to not resembly C style, declare variables as close as possible to their first use.
Then: why don't you use `Long`? Probably even better would be `Double` in your arraylist, as this removes the need for a cast in mixed type operations.

Comment: You can make `count` and `choosenOne` a `long`.